# Can I get all instances of some class in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, mvvm

I have implemented `QAbstractItemModel` and `QSortFilterProxyModel` with it as a source model. I have one `itemModel` instance and several `filterModel` instances. In each `filterModel` I have some variable value of which is calculated based on filtered data from `itemModel`. When `itemModel` is recreated (all items removed and the new ones are inserted back) value of this variable should be set to default (or just be recalculated after filtering is done).

The problem is that I don't have some list of pointers to `filterModel` instances to iterate by them. Sure I can create such static list in constructor. But probably MOC did it instead of me and saved such list inside of `QMetaObject` of this class?

Comment: why not just use `modelReset` signal (or similar)?

Comment: Global object tracking has horrible performance in modern, multi-threaded applications. Qt, rightly, doesn't do it for you - what would be the point? `QObject` is a fairly lightweight class, adding the overhead of global tracking would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter proxy implementation is broken. The proxies are fully informed of each and every change to the model - that's why the models are `QObject`s and emit change signals! There's nothing preventing you from changing the "some variable" as appropriate, when the source model indicates that it has changed.

You need to think of your "some variable" as depending on some data (and structure!) from the source model. Every time the source model indicates changes to the dependent data or structure, your proxy must recompute the value - or at least set a flag so that the value might be recomputed lazily when needed.